# Use same test-main for generic and static vector class by using template/alias

Tags: c++, templates, vector, assert

We were given a test-main for our own 3-float Vector class called "Vec3f", which was to be realized with an array. After doing so we were told to convert it into a generic vector class for any datatype and N´s. 
The test-main for this class was supposed to stay the same, we were told to make it run by using aliasing.

The teachers test class works with asserts and thats where the problem lies.
The 3 float Vector class was called Vec3f and this was substituted with Vec in the generic one. 
For example :

```
cout << "  value type and dimension: ";
        assert((typeid(Vec3f::value_type).name() == typeid(float).name()));
        assert((Vec3f::dimension == 3));

        cout << "passed." << endl;
```

So far so good but after declaring aliasing , for the generic one: `"using Vec3f = Vec<float,3>;"` 
It throws many assert errors.

"Class Vec<3,float> does not have any member called "value_type" or "dimension". Error 0135
Or it says assert is not defined properly . Of course I included cassert.

We are supposed to use only an std array . No further variables. So I cannot declare value_type and dimension....
Sometimes it even says cout is ambiguous, I have no Idea why . Thank you for your help. Stackoverflow does something with the inlcudes so I threw them out sry.

"Start of main class without includes"

```
//using namespace my;
using namespace std;
void test_Vec() {

    using Vec3f = Vec<float,3>;

ifndef NDEBUG
    cout << "======================" << endl;
    cout << "     Testing Vec      " << endl;
    cout << "======================" << endl;

    {
        cout << "  value type and dimension: ";
        assert((typeid(Vec3f::value_type).name() == typeid(float).name()));
        assert((Vec3f::dimension == 3));

        cout << "passed." << endl;
    }
```

.......

Comment: Do you have `value_type` and `dimension` in `Vec<float,3>`? Is your "old" `Vec3f` pass test?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @ your teacher: `static_assert(std::is_same<float, Vec3f::value_type>::value, "!");` instead of `assert`.